# Cannot import file installed with Anaconda in pyCharm: Need to add anaconda to Python PATH?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda, openai-gym

I am a newbie in Python and I wanted to run some reinforcement learning algorithms with Python using AI Gym: 
https://github.com/openai/gym

I want to use tensorflow so I made a python 3.5 environment called "tensorflow" with Anaconda and installed it there. In the same environment, I installed AIgym using

> pip install gym

from the Anaconda prompt. 
With

> conda list

I can see "gym" as a package installed in that environment, but in Anaconda Navigator it is not listed (neither in the "tensofrflow" environment or anywhere else.

Anyhow if I try to do

> import gym

I get

> No module named 'gym'

I am sure I have the Anaconda interpreter selected in the project configurations. I also tried

> pip install gym

from the regular command-line prompt but it still would refuse to find 'gym'.

One suggestion was to include the Anaconda path to the system's Python PATH. I am not sure how to do this correctly. Most advice is for Linux and I use Windows 10. Is it the path of the python.exe inside the anaconda folder? I've seen people trying

> export PATH=C:/path/anaconda:$PATH

but export is not recognized for me in any command prompt.

> which python

is also not recognized in order to check which python is being used.
I also tried adding the anaconda path to the system path (This PC > Advanced > Environment Variables > System Variables > Path) but no dice.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

--Update 1--

Thomas, thanks for your answer. I have tried what you suggested - tried importing gym from the python in-line interpreter from within the anaconda prompt/environment, and it worked!

cmd
[image: cmd]

In pyCharm, though, even while I am sure I have the Anaconda interpreter selected for the project, it doesn't work.

PyCharm
[image: pyCharm]

--Update 2--
I can see my envs and path but how exactly do you add an env in pyCharm?
The method I have been using was, configure the project to use the Anaconda interpreter and switch environments from the anaconda prompt.
A search gives the same answer.

[image: env_advice]

It is strange because I have tensorflow installed only in my tensorflow environment, and tensorflow itself imports without problem, as you can see here:

[image: tf_import]

Thus the tensorflow environment must be active.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try go to _Start_ -> _Anaconda (64/32-bit)_ -> _Anaconda Prompt_ to run the Anaconda "version" of Python.

Comment: But if you have added to PATH, then it should also work from cmd I think

Comment: Thomas, I edited my question for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your *cmd*-example, you're using an environment called *tensorflow*, and not the "root" (aka default) environment. You can add that same environment to PyCharm, and use *that* instead.

If you're unsure of where the environment is located you can use the conda command `conda env list`, i.e.:

```
(tensorflow) C:\Users\Riel> conda env list
```

That will print a list of the installed Anaconda environments and their locations. Find your *tensorflow* environment and add it to PyCharm.

When I do it on my system, I get this output:

```
# conda environments:
#
benv                     E:\Anaconda3\envs\benv
game                     E:\Anaconda3\envs\game
ml                       E:\Anaconda3\envs\ml
py26                     E:\Anaconda3\envs\py26
py27                     E:\Anaconda3\envs\py27
py33                     E:\Anaconda3\envs\py33
py34                     E:\Anaconda3\envs\py34
py35                     E:\Anaconda3\envs\py35
py36                     E:\Anaconda3\envs\py36
root                  *  E:\Anaconda3
```

### Adding environment to PyCharm

To [add the environment to PyCharm](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Configuring+Interpreters+with+PyCharm#ConfiguringInterpreterswithPyCharm-Localinterpreter), select from the menu bar:

*File* -> *Settings*.. -> *Project Interpreter* -> Click the cog wheel -> *Add Local*

Then find the folder of your *tensorflow* environment and the *python.exe*-file in it and add it, which according to your image, is G:\Programs\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\python.exe

(See image below)

[image]

Comment: Dear Thomas, Edited with Update 2.

Comment: I've updated the answer with instructions on how to add your _tensorflow_ environment as the project interpreter in PyCharm.

Comment: Dear Thomas, it worked! Thanks for your valuable help. It was such a simple fix that I'm surprised I didn't find good and precise instructions like yours during searching. I had assumed, by what I've read, that the way Anaconda worked was by using the Anaconda interpreter and changing the environment from Anaconda itself, not that I had to use a separate interpreter for each environment.